# Aggregate uploaded files for simplified download

Tags: 7, files

I have a content type that users are uploading a *lot* of files into, and the client would like to be able to download all of the attached files with a single click. It seems that a server-side compression of all the files would be a good solution, something like Stephen.Colson is trying to do here [stephen.colson's sandbox](http://drupal.org/sandbox/stephen.colson/1127214).

I haven't found anything appropriate, though. Is anyone aware of a good solution for aggregating file downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [pclzip](http://drupal.org/project/pclzip) suite of modules [ZipCart](http://drupal.org/project/zipcart).

Comment: PCLZip is an excellent suggestion and pretty much what I needed. It was not, however, that straightforward, as the instructions are a bit lacking. For anyone following in my footsteps, here are some good things to know:

Comment: 1. This is actually a cluster of modules and you'll need at least one of these others to make it work:

 * [pclzip_zipfolder](http://drupal.org/project/pclzip_zipfolder)
 * [pclzip_zip_node_files](http://drupal.org/project/pclzip_zip_node_files)
 * [pclzip_zip_content_files](http://drupal.org/project/pclzip_zip_content_files)

2. I used the `pclzip_zip_node_files` and it adds a get_zip part to the URL, so to download all of the files, you need the `baseurl.com/node/nid/get_zip`